# Mootools 1.3.2 & IE8 Only Error, Object doesn't support property/method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mootools

My script is throwing an error only in IE8. I'm using Mootools 1.3.

The error thrown is:

Object doesn't support this property/method.

The IE8 debugger is telling me that the error is this (line with **):

```
append: function(original){
    for (var i = 1, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++){
        var extended = arguments[i] || {};
        **for (var key in extended) original[key] = extended[key];**
    }
    return original;
}
```

The above code is around line 380 in the uncompressed version. It's part of Object.extend.

Now I am suspecting this is happening when I do a each on an array like object. This is the code I'm suspecting is triggering this:

```
var self = this,
    c = certManager.addedCerts,
    e = window.expManager.workExp,
    cA = this.cA = [],
    eA = this.eA = [];
    c.each(function(x){
        cA.push(x.value);
    });
    e.each(function(x){
        eA.push(x.retrieve('info'));
    });
```

The first array (c) is populated with numbers only. The second one (e) is populated with objects that have a store/retrieve going on.

The array like objects are declared like so:

```
addedCerts = this.addedCerts = []

workExp = this.workExp = []
```

in their respective modules (certManager & expManager).

Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?

EDIT:

As requested, here's how workExp is populated:

```
var r = $('resumeContent'),
                h = "<div class=\"contentRowRight\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"xHover remove\" > </a><br/>" + yV + " " + mV + "</div><strong>" + pV + "</strong><br />" + cV,
                n = new Element('div', {html: h, 'class': 'contentRow'}).inject(r, 'top');
            n.getElement('.remove').addEvents({
                'click': function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    self.removeExp(this);
                },
                'mouseover': function(){
                    var el = this;
                    this.store('mO', true);
                    (function() {
                        if (el.retrieve('mO')){
                            el.fieldToolTip('Remove Experience',false,false);
                            el.store('mO', false);
                        }
                    }).delay(500);
                },
                'mouseout': function(){
                    this.store('mO', false);
                    this.removeToolTip();
                }
            });
            n.store('info', {'p': pV, 'c': cV, 'y': yV.replace(' year', '').replace('s', '').replace(' and', ''), 'm': mV.replace('month', '').replace('s', '')});
            this.workExp[this.workExp.length] = n;
```

What I have going on is part of a form. I have a few fields inside a form, you fill them in and then click the Add button and it creates a new 'row'. Those rows contain information about a users work experience. Once the user as added all his work experience, he can keep filling the form. Once the form is all filled out, I iterate over the array object and transform the values into a JSON object which I then put in a hidden value and pass it to the back end.

If you guys want to see the script in action, you can visit http://www.oilforce.com/user-signup.php. You will be forced to fill the first page which is personal info (you can type in garbage, it's not like you're gonna submit it anyways) and then press next 3 times. On the fourth page, the work experience form is there. That's what the code above is doing.

Comment: show me where you define `workExp = this.workExp = []` - or rather, where you populate the array and what with. the ONLY line here that is on show capable of causing this error is `eA.push(x.retrieve('info'));` as this is the only element prototype related call and in IE8, `Element.prototype` cannot be natively extended so the methods (such as `.retrieve`) are applied on the element objects directly at the time they pass through a selector ($, $$, getElement, getElements or the new Element constructor).

Comment: the serialization of the form can be done automatically by mootools, btw.

Comment: why are you ending your lines with comas??? i.e. `var self = this,
    c = certManager.addedCerts,` be carefoul with that kind of stuff.. browsers like FF are very permissive with syntaxes, but IE wont stand for it and it will throw errors, and don't trust the errorLine..

Comment: it's to avoid using the var keyword over and over again. Instead you just define all your variables on one line.

Comment: Alright, I think I found my problem. I had a field named 'position' which was apparently clashing with ie8. I renamed it to 'pos' where appropriate and it doesn't throw an error anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was stemming from a field I had in my form. The id of the field was 'position' which apparently clashed with something in ie8. Renamed my field to 'pos' and everything seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the exact same error.

My code is very simple:

```
alert(document.id('YouTubeFlashPlayer').get('id'));
```

However it is run via Element.addEvent() inside a MooTools Class object. The offending method above is

```
.get()
```

It's as if IE8 is *completely ignoring the MooTools extended methods*, since

```
document.id('YouTubeFlashPlayer')
```

will in fact alert an HTML object.

I'm almost at the end of my rope with IE8. I'm considering banishing it via

```
if(Browser.ie8) document.getElement('body').dispose();
```

Comment: you are doing something wrong. in this instance, `YouTubeFlashPlayer` will be extended - except for if its of type OBJECT or APPLET, in which case it won't (iirc). use a wrapper element around your player and work with that, bubbling down when you can. Or, use native methods like `.getAttribute` and reference properties direct.

Answer (score 0):

ok i was debugging the code a little bit.. and i think your problem is when you try to display the tooltip for the validation message. My guess is that there's a problem with the sound that the tooltip has to play.

My advice would be to change this line:

```
validateStep: function(x) {
 ...
 // line 6230
 this.fields[i].fieldToolTip('Your ' + names[i] + ' should be a minimum of ' + (lengths[i]+1) + ' characters.');
```

to a simple `alert()` (or maybe just comment this line) just to see if this is the problem. If this is the problem, you can disable the sound and hopefully you wont have this problem

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm pretty confident that's not it. The code above relates to form validation which works fine on IE8. The tooltips are shown. The error is thrown on the final submission of the form. Once all my fields are validated, I call a function named 'submitForm' (How convenient? haha) and the error is only thrown once that function is called. There is no validation happening at that point, it's already been done. As Dimitar mentionned above, it is likely a problem with the retrieve method. Thank you for trying tho.

Comment: hmmm weird.. cause form validation doesn't work for me in IE8, it throws the exact same error, and the backtrace tells me this is where it all starts.. i just visited your site and clicked "Next" without writing anything

Comment: Actually, I just tried and that thing is throwing an error too. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I fixed this problem with a try...catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you use compilation for your project you may consider to try at the top of your entry point (file)

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support